# Why is the group of sections of a sheaf of modules given by the group of morphisms of sheaves?

Tags: modules, sheaf-theory, schemes, ringed-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ be a ringed space and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules. Why is it true that
$$
\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{X}|_{U}} \left( \mathcal{O}_{X}|_{U} , \mathcal{F}|_{U}  \right) = \mathcal{F}(U)?
$$ 
I feel like this should be obvious, but I am not seeing what the isomorphism is. How does a family of maps on the groups of sections for subsets $V \subseteq U$ correspond to an element of the module $\mathcal{F}(U)$?

Comment: This is a sheaf-theoretic version of the isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A,M)\simeq M$ if $A$ is any algebra and $M$ any $A$-module. The isomorphism from left to right is $\varphi\mapsto\varphi_U(1)$. From right to left, this is $x\in\mathcal{F}(U)\mapsto (s\in\mathcal{O}_X(V)\mapsto s.x|_V)$. Check that this is well defined and that these two maps are inverse to each other.